# Can I have pylint warn of suppression lines that would be unnecessary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pylint

With pylint, is it possible to tell it to output warnings on lines that explicitly disable a particular warning, but where the warning doesn't actually occur?

The idea here would be that sometimes I'd like to clean up the suppression lines I added, after refactoring the code.

Now the obvious method would be to remove all suppression lines and then add them back one by one. But since pylint knows about the code and what I ask of it using suppression lines, it'd be better equipped to point out unnecessary suppression lines.

Can pylint do this?

I tried to search for this feature, but came up empty-handed. So I probably picked the wrong search terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for *useless-suppression*, as in *pylint --enable=useless-suppression*. It is disabled by default.

Comment: Indeed this looks like it. I'll verify and accept your answer if that's the case. Thank you! In fact I'll probably award you a bounty as well.